# How can i map Hive table with HBase table?

Tags: hbase, hiveql

I have created a HBase table like the following:

> create 'nancy', 'cf'

And created a table in Hive like below:

> create external table nancy( id int, name string)
>
> stored by 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
>
> WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key, cf:name")
>
> TBLPROPERTIES("hbase.table.name"="nancy");

Am I mapping it write? What does the Key in the "hbase.columns.mapping" signifies?

Can anyone explain this mapping?

Answer (score 5):

Are you facing any specific problem?Query looks OK to me.

**key** represents that you are using this field as the table key. Remember Every field in a hive table can be mapped to one of these :

- table key (using :key as selector)
- column family (cf:) (MAP fields in Hive
- column

**In response to your comments :**

```
hive> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE hbase_table_2(key int, name string)

    > STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
    > WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,cf:name")
    > TBLPROPERTIES("hbase.table.name" = "nancy");
OK
Time taken: 5.106 seconds

hive> select * from hbase_table_2;
OK
Time taken: 0.077 seconds

hive> INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE hbase_table_2 SELECT * FROM demo WHERE id=1;
Total MapReduce jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator
Starting Job = job_201308011237_0003, Tracking URL = http://localhost:50030/jobdetails.jsp?jobid=job_201308011237_0003
Kill Command = /Users/miqbal1/hadoop-eco/hadoop-1.1.2/libexec/../bin/hadoop job  -kill job_201308011237_0003
Hadoop job information for Stage-0: number of mappers: 1; number of reducers: 0
2013-08-01 16:29:21,832 Stage-0 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2013-08-01 16:29:23,843 Stage-0 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%
2013-08-01 16:29:24,849 Stage-0 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%
Ended Job = job_201308011237_0003
1 Rows loaded to hbase_table_2
MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
Job 0: Map: 1   HDFS Read: 256 HDFS Write: 0 SUCCESS
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 0 msec
OK
Time taken: 8.392 seconds
hive>
```

And this is my HBase table :

```
hbase(main):017:0> scan 'nancy'
ROW                                      COLUMN+CELL                                                                                                          
 1                                       column=cf:name, timestamp=1375354762803, value=tariq                                                                 
1 row(s) in 0.0300 seconds
```

Comment: Now i tried mapping a hive table to an existing HBase table.




CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE hbase_table_2(key int, name string)
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,cf:name")
TBLPROPERTIES("hbase.table.name" = "nancy");


It did not show any error but, the data in the HBase table is not displaying when i do a select *.

Comment: which table? Hbase?

hbase(main):001:0> describe 'nancy'
DESCRIPTION                                          ENABLED
 {NAME => 'nancy', FAMILIES => [{NAME => 'cf', BLOOM true
 FILTER => 'NONE', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0', VERSION
 S => '3', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', MIN_VERSIONS => '0
 ', TTL => '2147483647', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', IN_ME
 MORY => 'false', BLOCKCACHE => 'true'}]}
1 row(s) in 1.0500 seconds

Comment: I copied your command and it is working fine on my machine. See the edited answer..

Comment: I used put command.. i am able to create the table in Hive but there are no records in the table. In the HBase table there are records.

Comment: Put as well is working fine. Are you able to insert data through Hive?Anything interesting in hive.log?

Comment: in the HBase table, the following is how I have put my data.


hbase(main):001:0> scan 'nancy'
ROW                   COLUMN+CELL
 row1                 column=cf:a, timestamp=1375338887793, value=nancy
 row2                 column=cf:a, timestamp=1375340617269, value=mary
 row3                 column=cf:a, timestamp=1375340626864, value=maria
 row4                 column=cf:a, timestamp=1375340636988, value=sana


Is this right?

Comment: hey i got it.. it worked... I changed the 'row 1' to '1'.. now i am able to display data of HBase in Hive.

Comment: Glad to hear that you got it working. but i'm wondering why do you need to change the rowkey....

Answer (score 1):

Problem was with the whitespace character in columns mapping `":key, cf:name"`. Hive looks for a column family named **" cf"** instead of **"cf"**. Sİnce there is no space in Tariq's response (`":key,cf:name"`), it works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

you have two choice that map hive table with hbase table :

1. create a table that both hive and hbase can manager(e. delete )

   ```
   CREATE TABLE hbase_table_1(key int, name string)
   STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
   WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,cf:name")
   ```

   TBLPROPERTIES("hbase.table.name" = "nancy");
2. create an exteral table that managered by hbase

   ```
   CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE hbase_table_2(key int, name string) STORED BY
   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler' 
   WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,cf:name") 
   TBLPROPERTIES("hbase.table.name" = "nancy");
   ```

In both way you can inser by hive sql :

```
    insert into  hbase_table_1 select  1, "name1" ;
    insert into  hbase_table_2 select  2, "name2" ;
```

> hbase(main):011:0> scan 'nancy'
>
> ROW                                       COLUMN+CELL
>   1                                         column=cf:name,
>   timestamp=1491979916489, value=name1
>   2                                         column=cf:name,
>   timestamp=1491979928355, value=name2
>   2 row(s) in 0.3250 seconds

Comment: Be aware that you can not use sparksql to operator this insert sql or you will get error : Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HiveHBaseTableOutputFormat cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveOutputFormat